# Profile a node script that streams data

Tags: node.js, performance, csv, stream, profiling

I've written a node script that streams ~400K lines of CSV lines from two files using the `csv` npm modules (`csv-parse`, `csv-stringify`, `stream-transform`) using the `pipe` approach and writing to one output CSV file.  For each line, certain fields are deleted, changed or added.(*) I'm also using Ramda in the hope that it makes the script parallelizable and more performant.

First, I've forced the `parse` and `transform` steps to sequential mode using the `{parallel: 1}` and got these results:

```
$ time node index.js
INFO: loaded 252 geonames.
loadGeoNames: 50.537ms

real    3m1.603s
user    2m49.417s
sys     0m4.578s
```

Now, with `50` parallel callbacks, I save 8 seconds:

```
$ time node index.js
INFO: loaded 252 geonames.
loadGeoNames: 43.098ms

real    2m53.249s
user    2m47.690s
sys     0m3.554s
```

Then I changed that value to `100` and got these results:

```
$ time node index.js
INFO: loaded 252 geonames.
loadGeoNames: 47.953ms

real    2m46.461s
user    2m42.621s
sys     0m3.578s
```

So there is a difference of 15 seconds which doesn't look like much. Also, reading 400K lines (from two CSV files) and writing them to one file (also CSV) I would expect to be faster, but I don't really have much experience in that field.

I have no idea what the expected performance should/could be.  How can I find out where the script spends its time?

The script itself is here:
https://github.com/jfix/geoip-converter/blob/master/index.js

FWIW, I'm running this on a 2010 Macbook Pro with 8 GB of RAM.

(*) More specifically, the script transforms GeoIP data from one format to another one, as MaxMind has stopped updating the so-called 'legacy' format, but one can transform the new format (spread of several files) to the old one which is what I'm doing here. I've added some background information to the README of the repo.